# Google Maps Geocoding API Reporting

Tags: android, google-maps

We are using the Google Maps Geocoding API for an application that runs on iOS and Android.  I am trying to see if I can get any detailed reporting on device type usage by device type. I can see the overall usage, but I am not finding anything that will give me a breakdown of the queries.

Looking at the similar questions box at right, they are all more detailed about the code usage of the API itself. I am only looking for reporting, but Google refers to this site for their support (I am a technical writer). My project lead is balking at paying for support (I recognize I can go to Google if we get a higher level of support).   Is there any detailed reporting of API usage available?

Comment: What do you mean by detailed reporting on device type usage by device type? Wouldn't Google Analytics be enough for this or are you asking for there's a "Maps Analytics"?

Comment: It would be a MAPs analytics, yes.  I will look into Google Analytics, but that focus (from the documentation) appeared to be on Cloud Usage, not this specific API.  Thank you for the pointer.

Comment: I bounced around in the Google support organization for several weeks, as well as sales, and did not receive any help.  Wondering if there is any avenue at all for getting more detail on the numbers that Google billed us for?  We are using the Google Maps Geocoding API, and Google Analytics does not support the MAPs APIs.  We were billed for 100,000 hits per day, and cannot get a reporting about what makes up that number.  Any thoughts from anyone here?  Thank you